# Cloud-based Solidity Platform?

Tags: solidity

A few weeks back, I took a notion to look into Solidity. As a long-time developer, it seemed to me an important technology to know about.  I installed geth on my dev machine, and started the process of downloading the Ethereum blockchain. I soon discovered that my low-bandwidth connection (the fate of US rural denizens) would keep me waiting until the next decade before I could proceed to the next step.

My question is: does a cloud-based Solidity platform exist—one that would let me learn and play around without having to have a local copy of the blockchain?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write solidity contracts in your browser at: [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org). Remix, also sometimes referred to as Browser-solidity, is focused on contracts. It compiles your contracts and you can do some local testing.

You can also run a local node that doesn't link up to any public networks. Check out these directions for running your own network, which would not require a long download and allow you to learn about Ethereum locally.

[Ethereum Test Networks](https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/network/test-networks.rst#geth-go-client-1)

If you are looking to engage with public Dapps, then I think that you will be required to download at least some portion of either the main net or the test net. There are lots of Dapps available on the test net, and it's a bit less to download.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [ethercamp](https://live.ether.camp/) studio it is a cloude9 IDE version for Ethereum. You could write the code and test it without having to install anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at INFURA: https://infura.io.
INFURA removes the overhead that comes with hosting your own node.